# How to set UDP send buffers on Linux

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, udp

In my C++ program, I send many small (< KB) UDP messages. When I measure the performance of such UDP sends, I see that most of them complete under 300 milliseconds, but occasionally (every ~150), it takes 3 seconds.
Note that these measurements are taken over a wi-fi network, which probably explains the occasional delays. However, if I wanted to support the wi-fi scenario, I suspect that increasing the send buffers would be my first step.
My initial research pointed me to increasing the UDP buffer size via `net.core.rmem_max` and `net.core.rmem_default`, which I did:

```
$sudo sysctl net.core.rmem_max
net.core.rmem_max = 26214400
$sudo sysctl net.core.rmem_default
net.core.rmem_default = 26214400
```

However, this does not seem to have any impact on my program.
Next, I tried setting the buffer size in code:
`setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &size, size_len)`, where the size is `26214400`. This solved the issue - no more delayed packets. However, after examining the buffer size via `getsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &size, &size_len)`, I see that the buffer was set to `5228800`.

Hence, my question is: what is the proper way of increasing the UDP send buffer?

My environment:

```
cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
```

This issue only appears when I use wi-fi, which is the use case I want to support. In other words, I do not see the occasional slow sends when testing against an ethernet interface.

Here is my source code related to UDP:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cerrno>

#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

#include "udp_sender.h"

void soc_get_so_snd_buf(int socket_fd)
{
    unsigned int size = 0;
    socklen_t size_len = sizeof(size);

    if(getsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &size, &size_len) == -1 ) {
        std::string err_msg = "Failed to get the socket send buffer for socket: " + std::to_string(socket_fd);
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << err_msg;
        throw std::runtime_error(err_msg);
    }

    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "Send buffer size (SO_SNDBUF) is: " << size;
}

void soc_set_so_snd_buf(int sock_fd, size_t size)
{
    socklen_t size_len = sizeof(size);
    if (setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &size, size_len) == -1) {
        std::string err_msg = "Failed to set the socket send buffer to " + std::to_string(size);
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << err_msg;
        throw std::runtime_error(err_msg);
    }
}


UDPSender::UDPSender(int id) : my_id(id) {
    char my_ip[100];
    sprintf(my_ip, "10.1.1.%d", id);

    send_socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(send_socket_fd < 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create a send socket.");


    int enable = 1;
    if (setsockopt(send_socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to assign REUSADDR option.");
    }

    soc_get_so_snd_buf(send_socket_fd);
    soc_set_so_snd_buf(send_socket_fd, 26214400); // setting this to 26214400 results in 5228800 which seems to solve my issue for now.
    soc_get_so_snd_buf(send_socket_fd);

    struct sockaddr_in srcAddr{};
    memset(&srcAddr, 0, sizeof(srcAddr));
    srcAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srcAddr.sin_port = htons(0); // Any port will do.
    inet_pton(AF_INET, my_ip, &srcAddr.sin_addr);
    if(bind(send_socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&srcAddr, sizeof(srcAddr)) < 0) {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "Failed to bind sending socket " << strerror(errno);
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to bind a send socket.");
    }
}

UDPSender::~UDPSender() {
    close(send_socket_fd);
    send_socket_fd = -1;
}

ssize_t UDPSender::send(
    int dest_id,
    int dest_port,
    char* msg,
    size_t msg_size) const {

  
    char dest_ip[100];
    struct sockaddr_in dest_addr{};
    sprintf(dest_ip, "10.1.1.%d", dest_id);
    memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));
    dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest_addr.sin_port = htons(dest_port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, dest_ip, &dest_addr.sin_addr);
    
    ssize_t bytes_sent = sendto(
            send_socket_fd,
            msg,
            msg_size,
            0,
            (struct sockaddr*)&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr));
    if (bytes_sent < 0) {
        std::string error_msg = "Failed to send from: " +
                std::to_string(my_id) +
                " to: " +
                std::to_string(dest_id) + " errno: " + std::to_string(errno) + " ";
        error_msg += strerror(errno);

        if (errno == EPERM) {
            error_msg += "; error was due iptables bock rule - expected for some targets.";
            BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << error_msg;
            return 0;
        } else {
            BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << error_msg;
            throw std::runtime_error(error_msg);
        }
    }

     if (bytes_sent != msg_size) {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "Failed to send the expected number of bytes, wanted :"
            << msg_size << " sent " << bytes_sent;
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to send the expected number of bytes.");
    }

    return bytes_sent;
}
```

Tests:

```
#include "udp_sender.h"
#include "message_factory.h"
#include "heartbeats.h"

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

using namespace std::chrono;


TEST(UDPSenderTest, Broadcast) {
    int sender_id = 0;
    UDPSender sender = UDPSender(sender_id);
    char serialized[65000];
    Heartbeat msg = Heartbeat(sender_id, Peers{Node{2, 3}}, false);
    long serialized_size = MessageFactory::serialize_heartbeat(msg, serialized);

    auto start_cycle = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++) {
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        sender.send(i, 7777,  serialized, serialized_size);
        auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start);
        if (duration.count() > 300) {
            BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "Sent broadcast to " << i << " in " << duration.count() << " milliseconds";
        }

    }
    auto stop_cycle = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop_cycle - start_cycle);
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "Completed broadcast cycle in " << duration.count() << " milliseconds";
}
```

Output when I am not setting the socket options and instead rely on the Linux configuration:

```
 [ RUN      ] UDPSenderTest.Broadcast
37: [2022-10-06 09:56:08.183035] [0x00007f5f15f8b740] [debug]   Send buffer size (SO_SNDBUF) is: 212992
37: [2022-10-06 09:56:11.256173] [0x00007f5f15f8b740] [debug]   Sent broadcast to 247 in milliseconds 3069
37: [2022-10-06 09:56:11.256590] [0x00007f5f15f8b740] [debug]   Completed broadcast cycle in 3073 milliseconds
```

Comment: There's no way a UDP send took 3 seconds. The syscall might not have _returned_ for 3 seconds, if it chose to pre-empt your process and schedule something else, but even that's surprising unless your system is very heavily loaded.

Comment: My system is not loaded when I run the above test, and I can consistently reproduce the behavior I described.
Furthermore, increasing the buffer via the setsockopt also consistently solves the problem.

Comment: A UDP send should traditionally just silently drop the outgoing message when the send buffer is full (this is registered by the NOCANPUT stat on some systems). What platform is this happening on?

Comment: I bet the `send()` command, which is a method in your class, is doing some waiting.

Comment: @Useless: Updated my question with the OS version (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS).
@HenriqueBucher: Correct, the `send` method introduces the latency.

Comment: Your code should always send 256 packets, but you only show one. Did the other 255 really complete in 4ms? If you know the time is being taken in your `send` code, have you tried taking timestamps in _there_ to see exactly what is slow?

Comment: Are the packets going across wi-fi, by any chance?  If so, a wi-if renegotiation might explain the occasional delayed packet.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes, I am using wi-fi, and I can't repro the issue against an ethernet interface. I updated my question with this info.

Comment: @Useless I think that wi-fi explains the occasional slow packets, so I am considering closing this question and opening another one that focuses on the question of setting the buffer size.

Comment: @immutableT just one of the many ways in which Wi-Fi is terrible for timing-sensitive networking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the wrong kernel parameter.

The `net.core.rmem_default` and `net.core.rmem_max` parameters set the default and max sizes respectively of the UDP **receive** buffer.  The corresponding parameters for the UDP **send** buffer are `net.core.wmem_default` and `net.core.wmem_max`.

In general, the proper way to set the UDP send buffer for your program is with the `SO_SNDBUF` socket option, and the value you set will be limited by the `net.core.wmem_max` kernel parameter.  Then if you need a value larger than the max you can increase the value of `net.core.wmem_max`.

You don't typically want to modify `net.core.wmem_default` or `net.core.rmem_default` as that will affect other processes on the system.